# Web/maven project struture in eclipse Luna

Tags: maven, eclipse-luna

To start a new web project in Luna, I follow below steps.

1) Create a new Dynamic Web Project

2) Convert it into Maven by clicking configure option

The below is the obtained structure

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ph9M.jpg

This web project structure looks completely different from the one I see in the tutorial I follow. There the project structure is as follow

http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/Struts2-login-form-folder-stucture.jpg

I am not sure if the project structure is changed in new version or if I am doing something wrong. I made almost everything work but doesn't know where to place resources folder ( where we keep all our properties file ).

Can somebody assist me on how to create a new Struts2 project with proper structure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here in this tutorial :D

http://o7planning.org/web/fe/default/en/document/300723/struts2-tutorial-for-beginners-annotation-configuration

I should have created Maven Project and picked web-app archetype. It is very simple.